# Qt Installer Framework not registering file type

Tags: windows, qt, file-type, qt-installer

I am trying to use Qt Installer Framework (version 3.1 in windows) to create an installer of [my package](https://github.com/apalomer/image_view). The package that I am using for testing is an image viewer that can load a custom file format: .cjpg (which is essentially the same as jpg but with a different name). This project can be found [here](https://github.com/apalomer/image_view).

The pacakge `xml` file incorporates the following script:

```
function Component()
{
  // default constructor
}

Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
{
  component.createOperations();

  if (systemInfo.productType ==  "windows")
  {
    component.addOperation("Execute","{0,3010}","@TargetDir@/VC_redist.x64.exe","/quiet","/norestart");
    component.addOperation("CreateShortcut",
                   "@TargetDir@/image_view.exe",
                   "@StartMenuDir@/image_view.lnk",
                   "iconPath=@TargetDir@/image_view.ico")
    component.addOperation("CreateShortcut",
                   "@TargetDir@/image_view.exe",
                   "@DesktopDir@/image_view.lnk",
                   "iconPath=@TargetDir@/image_view.ico")
    component.addOperation("RegisterFileType",
                   ".cjpg",
                   "@TargetDir@/image_view.exe '%1'",
                   "Custom JPG file extension",
                   "text/plain",
                   "@TargetDir@/cjpg_file_icon.ico")
  }
}
```

This script installs the VC_redist because I compile using the MSVC compiler and, as far as I read, it is necessary. Moreover, it creates a desktop and a start menu shortcuts.  These three parts work fine. However, the part with the association of the new file type (.cjpg) with the program is not working (the icon is not shown and the program is not open wehen doble clicking the file). I've followed [this tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/qt-installer-framework-registerfileextension-example.html) to get to this point. The only difference that I appreciate regarding the file register operation is that the tutorial defines an icon id and a ProgId. If I try to change that part to:

```
    component.addOperation("RegisterFileType",
                   ".cjpg",
                   "@TargetDir@/image_view.exe '%1'",
                   "Custom JPG file extension",
                   "text/plain",
                   "@TargetDir@/cjpg_file_icon.ico",
                   "ProgId=ImageViewer.cjpg")
```

The file is still not properly assocaited (the icon is not shown and the program is not open wehen doble clicking the file). If I try to change that part to:

```
    component.addOperation("RegisterFileType",
                   ".cjpg",
                   "@TargetDir@/image_view.exe '%1'",
                   "Custom JPG file extension",
                   "text/plain",
                   "@TargetDir@/cjpg_file_icon.ico", 0,
                   "ProgId=ImageViewer.cjpg")
```

or:

```
    component.addOperation("RegisterFileType",
                   ".cjpg",
                   "@TargetDir@/image_view.exe '%1'",
                   "Custom JPG file extension",
                   "text/plain",
                   "@TargetDir@/cjpg_file_icon.ico", "iconId=0",
                   "ProgId=ImageViewer.cjpg")
```

I get the following error during installation:

```
Error during installation process (com.vendor.image_view):
Invalid arguments in RegisterFileType: 6 arguments given, 2 to 5 arguments expected in the form: <extension> <command> [description[contentType[icon]]].
```

Any ideas on how to properly associate the file extension with the provided icon file and the program?

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows;

```
component.addOperation("RegisterFileType",
               ".cjpg",
               "@TargetDir@/image_view.exe \"%1\"",
               "Custom JPG file extension",
               "text/plain",
               "@TargetDir@/cjpg_file_icon.ico",
               "ProgId=ImageViewer.cjpg")
```

I added **"%1"** instead of **'%1'**.

Comment: Not that you should not add the leading "." in the ".ext", so it should be `"RegisterFileType", "cjpg"`. It is prepended for you, see https://github.com/qtproject/installer-framework/blob/0ec58b6586f688c7d46c707c3eedfcc807387c3f/src/libs/installer/registerfiletypeoperation.cpp#L111